# Not able to customize Access Denied exception on Symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony, symfony5, symfony5.4

I am making a project in Symfony 5 where there are multiple roles with different privileges. The problem is that when a user tries to log in a zone where they don't have enough privileges (e.g. a USER in an ADMIN only zone) it throws an Access Denied exception and I want to show a custom message instead of the Symfony error screen.

[AccessDeniedException error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qZX.png)

The security part has been done with the *access_control* method (in case that helps).
I've tried following the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html#customize-the-forbidden-response)  related to this matter but I can't find the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the message and not change the response or the error code itself you can just [customize the error template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates) by creating a `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error403.html.twig` template and clearing your caches.

The page won't be shown in the `dev` environment, though, because the default error page is more helpful during development. You can [still preview it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development) by accessing `/_error/403`.

Comment: So the user will automatically see the custom error instead of the Symfony one? I don't have to change something else apart from what you've said?

Comment: Yes, but as I said it won't work in the `dev` environment, as the default debug error page is more useful in development; but it'll show in the `prod` environment and can be customized to use your site template.